Multiple arrays within a array in nested JSON:(Key values not appearing)
I am trying to flatten a nested json using pyspark with following structure:
root
 |-- response: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- message: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- result: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- 1234568895: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Card: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Card_Number1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Card_Number1.displayValue: string (nullable = true)
        -- 1234568896: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Card: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Card_Number1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Card_Number1.displayValue: string (nullable = true)
        -- 1234568897: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Card: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Card_Number1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Card_Number1.displayValue: string (nullable = true)

I need an output like this:
id          Card    Card_Number1    Card_Number1.displayValue
1234568895  xx  xxx         xxxxx
1234568896  yy  yyy         yyyyy
1234568897  zz  zzz         zzzzz.

I am using the following :
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("NestedJSONExample").getOrCreate()    

df = spark.read.format("json").option("multiLine",True).option("header",True).option("inferschema",True).load("Files.json")       
df2 = df.selectExpr('inline(response.result)')

df2.show()

But I am getting the result, without the keys and only the values. How to proceed to get the desired output.

Why use spark when this is so easy to process by hand?  json.load and a simple loop.

You are right...But I am working in MS Fabric notebooks. So pyspark is default. So when i try to change this pyspark dataframe to pandas df, i am still losing the key values.Now I have to find a way to work this out in pyspark or I have to reinstate the keyvalues when changing to pandas df.

But you can read it using the json.load into a Python structure, then pick out whatever pieces you need, and import that into spark, right?

The notebook I am writing is a part of ADF pipeline, in fabric. I am downloading the data using API in json format to my lakehouse dynamically. Then using the notebook (which can support pyspark only to load data from lakehouse) to transform and clean the data. I load the data using df = spark.read.json("Files/{folder_structure}/{file_name}.json"). I tried converting pandas dataframe after exploding after this step, but due to nested structure, I am not getting the right output.

So, are you just ignoring my suggestions?  All you did is reiterate what's in your question.  I'm saying you can "preprocess" that JSON to fix whatever issues there are, THEN go into spark.

I hear you. But I guess I am not able to figure out how to do what you are saying, since I am still at coding basics. Let me research on how to do this.

I suggest you do import json / data = json.load('Files.json') / print(data) and see where that leads you.  Or maybe from pprint import pprint / pprint(json) to get a better look.

@TimRoberts this worked....thanks.....I was able to load the json, load only the required response as a df and then explode it in spark
